# TypeError: channel.updateOverwrite is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Im trying to make a lock channel command but Im getting the following error:
`TypeError: channel.updateOverwrite is not a function`

I have tried changing it to `channel.overwritePermissions` but it does not work.
Any help works, thanks in advance

EDIT: Changing it to message.channel.updateOverwrite does not work, it locks the channel where you sent the message instead of the channel mentioned

EDIT2: The problem has been solved, I just had to add `let channel = message.mentions.channels.first()` in the code, I have edited the code.

Its the same for the unlock command

Heres the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    category: 'Moderation',
    name: 'lock',
    commands: 'lock',
    description: 'Locks the specified channel!',
    callback: (message, args, channel, text) => {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_CHANNELS'))
            return message.reply('<:nomark:791577754659192832> You dont have the necessary permissions to use this command!');
        if (!args[0])
            return message.reply('<:nomark:791577754659192832> You need to mention a channel!');
        if (!message.mentions.channels.first())
            return message.reply('<:nomark:791577754659192832> You need to mention VALID a channel!');

        const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "@everyone");
        if (!role) return message.channel.send('Role is not able to be found.')

        message.mentions.channels.forEach(channel => {
            if (channel.name.startsWith(""))
                return message.channel.send(`<#${channel.id}> is already locked!`)
            channel.setName(`${channel.name}`);
            try {
                channel.updateOverwrite(role, {
                    SEND_MESSAGES: false
                });
                message.channel.send(`<#${channel.id}> has been locked!`);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
                message.channel.send(`Something has went wrong when locking the channels.`);
            }
        })

        channel.updateOverwrite(message.author, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide a runnable snippet

Comment: Have you tried using **message.channel.updateOverwrite** instead?

Comment: Changing it to message.channel.updateOverwrite does not work, it locks the channel where you sent the message instead of the channel mentioned

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved, I just had to add let channel = message.mentions.channels.first() in the code, I have edited the code